# C#: Verify password hash (SHA512) with salt for linux user from /etc/shadow

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, salt, password-hash

I want to verify the user credentials (*name and password*) for Linux users with native C# code (.NET Core).
The user credentials on Linux systems are normally stored in the file: **/etc/shadow**.

For example the user called "**csharp**" with the password "**1337**" has the following entry inside the file **/etc/shadow**:

```cs
string entry = "csharp:$6$qVnvjWpk$DOUTmbC9ROZ6s1h0hCZTYWLFfVeUWDbz8f0EUFPEJEC2UKQV0gRiIfoGpnaA.8i4RCcrGpOEHEd9xrAUDpo3Y/:18337:0:99999:7:::"
```

- The string before the first ":" is the name of the user => **entry.Split(":")[0]** (csharp)
- The char after the first "$" is the hash method => **entry.Split("$")[1]** (6 = SHA256). Possible methods are: MD5 => 1; SHA256 => 5; SHA512 => 6
- The string after the second "$" is the salt (or hash?) => **entry.Split("$")[2]** (qVnvjWpk)

When using the program **openssl** on the Linux system with "***openssl passwd -6 -salt qVnvjWpk 1337***", then it will give me the following output:
`$6$qVnvjWpk$DOUTmbC9ROZ6s1h0hCZTYWLFfVeUWDbz8f0EUFPEJEC2UKQV0gRiIfoGpnaA.8i4RCcrGpOEHEd9xrAUDpo3Y/`

As you can see, the openssl output is part of the **/etc/shadow** entry:

```cs
entry.Split(":")[1] == openssl_output
```

But how could this be done using native csharp code and without using the program openssl?

I have the following approach for doing this.

```cs
CheckCredentials("csharp", "1337");
```

```cs
public static bool CheckCredentials(string username, string password) {

    string[] shadow = File.ReadAllLines("/etc/shadow");

    foreach(string entry in shadow) {
        // entry = csharp:$6$qVnvjWpk$DOUTmbC9ROZ6s1h0hCZTYWLFfVeUWDbz8f0EUFPEJEC2UKQV0gRiIfoGpnaA.8i4RCcrGpOEHEd9xrAUDpo3Y/:18337:0:99999:7:::
        if(entry.Split(":")[0] == username) {

            // hash = 6f0ac65fe01188660aad900bfe16c566ebf0e56c0a7d4a15bd831049108de80bd3a2fbf1a8b91662433a40458ec208a207cab073f190bd65b889e95e4fca8e09
            // $6 => SHA512 
            string hash = HashSHA512(password);

            // salt = qVnvjWpk
            string salt = entry.Split("$")[2];

            // >>> how to check now the given password "1337"? <<< 

            break; 
        }

        throw new Exception($"User '{username}' was not found");

    }

    return false;

}
```

```cs
public static string HashSHA512(string input)
{
    SHA512Managed crypt = new SHA512Managed();
    StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

    foreach (byte append in crypto)
    {
        hash.Append(append.ToString("x2"));
    }
    return hash.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I need to do the same, verify passwords from an old database with a new application. It seems to be [extremely complicated](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt). I better find a library for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed complicated. I found some code that implemented the [original specification](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) [in C#](https://gist.github.com/otac0n/1092558). It was [extended](https://github.com/ahall/PasswordSharp) by SHA-512 support. Then I made [some more changes](https://gist.github.com/otac0n/1092558#gistcomment-3436400) to it and can now use it myself. [Here's the code.](https://gist.github.com/ygoe/33832285434eac3dc299a2b821470d19) (There's really not much more to mention in this answer...)